# path to current file inside requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, requirements.txt

I want to break my project into several interdependent modules which can be used inside my other projects separately. I'm not a professional python developer, so probably i'm doing something wrong.

Currently i came up to following idea:

```
my_collection_of_packages/
    package1/
        package1/
            some.py
        setup.py
        requirements.txt
    package2/
        same_structure_as_package1
        requirements.txt
project1/
    requirements.txt
```

`package1` doesn't depends on other packages, `package2` depends on `package1`, so `package2/requirements.txt` contains following string

```
-e ../package1/
```

So i can install `package1` during installation of `package2`

But if `project1` depends on `package2` i have a problem. Suppose my `project1/requirements.txt` looks like:

```
-e ../my_collection_of_packages/package2/
```

As far as i can understand, `pip` uses current working directory to resolve relative paths which means that if i try to install `project1/requirements.txt` it will treat `-e ../package1/` inside `package2/requirements.txt` as `project1/../package1/` which is wrong path.

I pretty sure it's possible to solve such problem by using absolute paths, but i want to avoid absolute paths.

Also it's possible to use git/wheels, but it's not very suited for me.

So my questions is:

1) Is it possible to specify inside `requirements.txt` path relative to current `requirements.txt`? Something like `-e ${current_requirements_pwd}/../package2`

2) What is the right way to manage my packages which i want to use in several projects and which can depend on other packages?

Sorry for my English

**UPDATE1**

It's looks like pip supports env variables in requirements.txt! But i have no idea which i should use for current requirements.txt. Looks like ${PWD} is current working dir.

Custom env variable which points to folder with my packages can be solution to my problem, but i want to avoid it too, if it possible